# Bracha on Tzitzit

Tags: halacha, time, tzitzis, sleep, intent-accident-purposely

If one takes a nap and has the intent to put tzitzit back on, does he need to make a new bracha when he does so?  Is it considered hesach hadaas (loss of concentration)?  Or does his intent obviate that issue?  What is the time period required?

Comment: I seem to recall that prior intent ***interrupted*** is still considered a hefsek. When you're asleep, you aren't actively intending anything about your tzitzit, despite what you thought ***before*** you took a nap.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55799

Answer (score 1):

I heard from Rav Gershon Meltzer a  posek  in yeshivas Mir that if you had intention to put it back on its not called a hefsek. Same issue with repeating birchas hatorah since you intend to wake soon after. He waif at most its a safek and safek brachos lekula. He suggested to sleep in them none theless in order to accommodate all opinions

Note this site is not meant for halachic rulings and thus should not be followed practically

Comment: Or just put on a different pair upon awaking.

Comment: I guess also have /n mind that you are being mafsik and for sure when you wake up you'll have to make a new brocho

Comment: Truthfully this question is dependent on whether if it falls off even by accident do you need to make a new brocho. The gra says you do